# Shaded area in R only with point in axis Y

Tags: r, area

For example I have just the data for Y:

```
55.64
79.21
47.8
28.52
43.99
83.02
87.04
85.44
```

But I'd like to plot a shaded area with that data, is that possible?

Comment: You need an x data, which you have to build artificially, e.g. using `x <- seq_along(y)`. BtW: please be more specific in your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about what you want to achieve but here is a way to color the area under the line defined by `Y` (assuming the corresponding x values are 1 to `length(Y)`), either with plain color or with shading lines:

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
# plain color (grey)
plot(seq(Y), Y, type="l", main="plain color")
polygon(c(1, seq(Y), length(Y)), c(0, Y, 0), col="grey")
# shading lines
plot(seq(Y), Y, type="l", main="shading lines")
polygon(c(1, seq(Y), length(Y)), c(0, Y, 0), density=10)
```

[image]